# xrandr: jail mouse

Tags: mouse, xrandr

I am using `xrandr` via console to enable/disable secondary monitors. This work fine so far. Unfortunately if I move my mouse beyond one screen, it appears on the other one. How can I disable this feature - and lock the mouse to one screen?

I use Ubuntu 10.10 and awesome - no GNOME/KDE.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: This question should be **reopened** because it is very clear and well specified. (Maybe after an edit) Ant it is a **relevant question**, everybody using two screens has it, and it can be extremely annoying, for example when a scrollbar is near the screen border, and the mouse is configured somewhat fast. Reaching for the scrollbar switches screens when moving the pointer about 5 pixel too far.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [XCreateMouseVoid](https://github.com/cas--/XCreateMouseVoid) to prevent mouse from entering rectangular areas on your (combined) screen, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42596/how-to-easily-open-the-launcher-with-a-secondary-monitor-to-the-left) for example setup. Use `xrandr -q` to figure out the parameters for XCreateMouseVoid.