# How to align twinview monitors with different resolutions and prevent mouse disappearing into dead areas?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, mouse, twinview

I'm using two monitors of different brands and resolutions with NVIDIA TwinView, which works well enough, but one thing that's getting to me is how the mouse can move off the edge of the visible screen space below the left-hand screen and above the right-hand screen (see screenshot).

It makes it much more difficult to hit buttons at the bottom/top of each screen, since the cursor just disappears off the edge. Is there a way of changing this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse moving into those dead areas is a known [X bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/389519) however there is a workaround using [XCreateMouseVoid](https://github.com/cas--/XCreateMouseVoid) that I have detailed in this question:

- [How to easily open the Launcher with a secondary monitor to the left](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42596/how-to-easily-open-the-launcher-with-a-secondary-monitor-to-the-left/42727#42727)

If you wish to just align the monitors along the top or bottom edges then modify the *Absolute Position* from `+1920+90` to `+1920+0` or `+1920+56`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Nvidia binary driver you can put:

Option "ConstrainCursor" "yes"

In the screen section of your xorg.conf. Indeed, this is the default behaviour.

This will prevent the mouse from entering any of the voids. However, it also prevents you from revealing the launcher by "pushing" against the edge of the screen, if you use Unity.